# Osgi is missing in eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse-plugin, osgi, spring-dm

I am trying to create an Spring DM application following this tutoria. I installed the osgi-extender libraries and included them in the target file but when I try to run the application I get:

```
org.eclipse.osgi plug-in is missing from this configuration.
```

https://angelozerr.wordpress.com/2012/04/06/eclipse_spring_step1/#createLaunch

Comment: I'm no expert on eclipse but are you sure you have the plugins installed as in the image at the link you posted? For example in that image I see the orgi.eclipse.osgi bundle ticked. Is it the same in your setup?

Comment: In my setup I can not see the equinox libraries. Even when I check when making a project, if I check equinox I still don't see the libraries.

Comment: Also I think Spring DM is not actively being developed so you might want to consider if you it's worthwhile trying to get the tutorial to work and follow a straight forward OSGi example.

Comment: and under org.eclipse.rcp in target I see only 5 plugins avalilable while in the tutorial there ere 31, but I don't know why. I use eclipse oxygen.

Comment: To be honest that tutorial scares the life out of me...and I've been using OSGi for several years It looks way to complex to set-up and would put anyone off trying to learn OSGi.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion of tutorial? I am not able to set up my project so far.

Comment: I have quite a few tutorials .. but only on blueprint and DS not spring dm. See https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial . If your just start I recommend using DS. For a really simple hello world see https://github.com/cschneider/osgi-ds-hello-world